# How to remove certain Stopwords from a section in a file, which starts and ends with specific characters

Tags: perl, cpu-word

```
.I 1
.T
Alice in wonderland
She follows it down a rabbit hole when suddenly 
she falls a long way to a curious hall with many locked doors of all sizes. 
She finds a small key to a door too small for her to fit through.
.B
CACM wolf dog December, 1958
.A
Perlis, A. J.
Samelson,K.
.N
CA581203 JB March 22, 1978  8:28 PM
.X
100 5   1
123 5   1
164 5   1
.I 2
.T
Extraction of Roots by Repeated Subtractions for Digital Computers
the contents of which cause her to shrink too small to reach the key
which she has left on the table.
A cake with "EAT ME" on it causes her to grow.
.B
CACM December, 1958
.A
Sugai, I.
.N
CA581202 JB March 22, 1978  8:29 PM
.X
2   5   2
2   5   2
2   5   2
```

Now the above text is the content of 2 files, new file starts from .I (followed by a number)
i need to do stopping in the text between .T & .B , .B & .A , .A & .N, .N &.X and remove all text between .X and start of new document. i.e. .I (followed by a number)

"Output should look like"

```
.I 1
.T
Alice wonderland
follows rabbit hole suddenly 
falls long way curious hall locked doors sizes 
door small fit through
.B
CACM wolf dog December, 1958
.A
Perlis, A. J.
Samelson,K.
.N
CA581203 JB March 22, 1978  8:28 PM
.X
.I 2
.T
Extraction Roots Repeated Subtractions Digital Computers
contents cause shrink
left table
cake with EAT causes grow
.B
CACM December, 1958
.A
Sugai, I.
.N
CA581202 JB March 22, 1978  8:29 PM
.X
```

i need to do stopping of words on the text which appears between .T & .B , .B & .A , .A & .N, .N &.X

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want. If I follow your directions, it seems I removing everything from the file. Can you clarify what you want, and maybe give us an example how the file should look after the program finishes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to get each chunk into a decent data structure. The following script does that. Once you have `%segments`, you can modify and reassemble each chunk as you wish.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %stops = map { $_ => 1 } qw(a all of in);
run(\*DATA, \%stops);

sub run {
    my $fh = shift;
    my $stops = shift;

    local $/ = '.I';

    my $pat = qr{
        ^[ ] (?<I> [0-9]+) \n
        ^[.] T \n (?<T> .+)
        ^[.] B \n (?<B> .+)
        ^[.] A \n (?<A> .+)
        ^[.] N \n (?<N> .+)
        ^[.] X \n (?<X> .+)
    }xms;

    while (my $chunk = <$fh>) {
        chomp $chunk;
        next unless $chunk;

        if ($chunk =~ $pat) {
            my %segments = %+;
            print Dumper \%segments;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new to perl, can you tell me where to load the file with all the contents

Comment: You open the file, and pass the filehandle to `run` as the first argument.